# Simplify sum of angles expression (Trigonometry)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm stuck on this.I need to simplify this given expression
$$\cot(\fracπ4+\theta)(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)$$
So far I simplified the first parentheses to $\frac{\cos\theta-\sin\theta}{\cos\theta\sin\theta}$ which I dont if this is correct but now I dont know how to multiply this by the second parenthesis

Comment: Let us continue what you started, writing $c$ for $\cos\theta$ and $s$ for $\sin\theta$: you already know the expression is $$A=\frac{c-s}{c+s}(c^2-s^2)$$ hence $$A=\frac{c-s}{c+s}(c-s)(c+s)=(c-s)^2=c^2+s^2-2cs.$$ Now, $c^2+s^2=1$ and $2cs=\sin(2\theta)$ hence $$A=1-2\sin\theta\cos\theta=1-\sin(2\theta).$$

Comment: @SimpleArt Yes I am sure I "did that right". Would you be kind enough to explain what is "by far incorrect" here?

Comment: @Did Oh my bad.  It wasn't very obvious with your $c's$ and $s's$.

Comment: You ought to put it in as an answer, not as a comment (in my opinion).

Answer (score -1):

Remember this:

$$\cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x) = \cos(2x)$$

and $$\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{4} - x \right) = \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + x\right)$$

Comment: OK, remembered. What is next? In other words: please explain how this is an answer.